# Fabricjs. Text selection doesn't fit to bounding box

Tags: fabricjs

When I select text in added to canvas iText2 object, it has some padding at the bottom. But when I do the same on fiddle I don't have such problem.
Please help me to understand because of what it happens.

[image]

Istead of

[image]

Comment: Please post a relevant snippet of your code

Comment: I cann't post all code from my project. But I will be grateful for any adviсe that will help to find the reason of this behavior

Comment: There are too many code abou fabricjs. iText2 object is created without any params instead of position. What someone else can effect in such way?

Comment: If you can't post the source code then narrow your data sample to the just one problem (the "Custom text") and use some **debugger** (e.g. Google Chrome Developer tools) . `fabric.js` is open source. If you use the unminified `fabric.js` file from the https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/tree/master/dist folder you'll be able to see the source code.Wild blind guessing on our side does not make sense (really)

Answer (score 1):

there.
please, check and change coordinate value of "pathOffset" attribute on text object or group object in fabric.js.
If you have question, let me know.

Comment: Or change "transformMatrix" attribute.
Please, check this demo.
http://fabricjs.com/matrix-transformation